# Apache CXF: adding custom documentation in the WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, documentation, jakarta-ee, cxf

I'm currently learning **Apache CXF**.

When CXF is generating a WSDL file from a Pojo, is there a way (a java annotation ?) to add a **custom documentation** to the WSDL file ? to describe a service or a parameter ?

I've already used @WebParam to set some  descriptive names but I'd like to add a longer documentation. Something like...

```
@WebService
@Documentation("This service say hello. See http://say.hello")
public interface MyService
  {
  @WebResult(name="helloMessage")
  @Documentation("Returns the hello message")
  public String sayHello();
  }
```

Thanks in advance,

Pierre

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[Apache CXF 2.3.0](http://cxf.apache.org/)** supports this.

[`@WSDLDocumentation`](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/annotations.html) **annotation to add documentation nodes to generated wsdl**